# Finding an instance in memory

Tags: javascript

I have a "common" library that is shared by multiple products. We have a "best practice" or a pattern whereby we expect a particular instantiation to use a particular name, so that it can be shared. So, for example, in a product you might see:

```
var manager = new Manager();
```

However, we like to use object literals for namespacing purposes, so the ideal would actually be:

```
myApp.manager = new Manager();
```

We're not currently doing it this more ideal way, because then the common code would have no great way of knowing about the manager. Back to the shared code, since the manager is optional (otherwise this discussion wouldn't even be a discussion), we have something like:

```
if (typeof manager !== "undefined") {
  // do stuff
}
```

It would be nice to check on all products if there's a manager available, without having to enforce that naming convention.

**The Question**

Is there a way to find an instance of "Manager" without iterating over the whole global scope? A one-liner to say, "Give me the first (or all) instance(s) of Manager"?

I've never come across such a thing, so I'm guessing there will just be raised eyebrows and "nah... you're crazy...", but I thought it might be worth asking.

---

**UPDATE**

So, the original question is being preserved for the general-purpose question, but as answers and comments rolled in, I got clobbered over the head with the realization that my specific implementation was important. So, chopped down to smaller pieces, here's the actual way the singleton is working:

```
var Manager = (function() {

  // the actual constructor
  function ManagerConstructor(opts) {
    // all the things that the manager actually does
  }

  var instance;

  // functions that are exposed on the Manager object; namely, just a way to invoke the constructor
  var exposed = {

    getInstance: function(opts) {

      if(typeof instance === "undefined") {          
        instance = new ManagerConstructor(opts);
      }

    return instance;
    }
  };

  return exposed;
})();
```

(there is definitely room for improvement)

And then when a manager is needed:

```
// in another file
var someManager = Manager.getInstance(opts); // opts only used
```

Now... in hindsight, I'm not sure we needed to implement it this way. There are Pros and Cons to this pattern in general, and more Cons as time goes by for our particular needs (though I can still see it being useful elsewhere!). But that's a matter for a refactoring discussion; wouldn't want to pollute the original specific question!

Comment: Looks like `Manager` should be a singleton.

Comment: It's a singleton all right, ibrahim. ;-) The particular imlementation of the singleton pattern actually uses `var manager = Manager.getInstance()` but I didn't want to complicate the question by discussing the way the singleton is implemented.

Comment: Do you use any build system at all ? Webpack for instance. In this case you could use the "global" export option. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#shimming-globals and the lodash example. What it does is basically telling the build system that if it encounters any "manager" variable, then include this module.

Comment: @adz5A we use Grunt. I looked into the Webpack Grunt module and couldn't get it to work. It became complicated by the fact that our files "depend on" files found in another project altogether. Now, the structure is dependable (you can use relative paths), but it's still external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it in the `Manager` class itself.

```
function Manager() {
    if (!Manager.manager) {
        Manager.manager = this;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can use:

```
if (!Manager.manager) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Waitasec... this... might work... in a modified way to suit the singleton pattern we actually use (the original question has simplified code). I'm going to scratch my head a bit at the cleverness of this, and give it a go.

Comment: I'm gonna have to go for this solution. It's so simple, but it does what I need it to do. I had to adapt it a bit (Manager isn't available until after the IIFE is run, but it's available by the time getInstance is invoked), but it works. Is easy.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly suggest using a standard module provider / bundler like Webpack or Browserify or similar, and using modules rather than shared globals.

But if you're going to use shared globals: Variables declared at global scope with `var` create enumerable properties on the global object, which you can access via `this` at global scope, or via the global `window`. So you could check each of them to see whether it's a manager:

```
var managerName = Object.keys(window).find(function(name) {
    return window[name] instanceof Manager;
});
```

or in some environments where accessing some things on `window` may be forbidden:

```
var managerName = Object.keys(window).find(function(name) {
    try {
        return window[name] instanceof Manager;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I don't recommend it. :-)

Live Example:

```js
function Manager() {
}

var someRandomName = new Manager();

// ...

var managerName = Object.keys(window).find(function(name) {
    try {
        return window[name] instanceof Manager;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
});
console.log("The name of the manager variable is: " + managerName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, TJ! We've had a Grunt process in place for so long that switching to Webpack or Browserify would be a hellish undertaking. For new projects, sure. For existing, not gonna happen. Your solution might be somewhat "ugly" in the way that I anticipated, but I will run a bit of perf testing on it and I might end up using it, thanks. I think swapping in "self" for "window" resolves the concern of window's availability.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for an identifier it will go up to all the way to the global scope before raising a ref error if it is not found. For your use case you need some kind of dependency management tool for which you can specify the value you want and it will instanciate it for you.

What you need makes me think of `require.js` which is kinda old stuff but still interesting in its design/api. It revolves around the idea of dependency injection.

https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep

```
  // Declarative
  define(dependencyArrayAsString, constructorFunction);

  // Lazy: this is just a "register" call
  define(["ajaxService"], function (ajax) {});


  // If you don't want to refactor you whole codebase and introduce new tools, this is a little
  // piece of code that could do the trick
  // First seperate services from other modules, services can be lazily
  // instantiated
  //
  const define = {
    __internalRegister: new Map()
  };

  // just a ref to use as placeholder, cause null / undefined are 
  // valid values in JS and you may be tempted to have a service which
  // is pure side effect...
  const NONE = {};

  // this function does not do a whole lot,
  // it register services without initializing them
  define.service = function (serviceName, dependencies, constructorFn) {
    if (this.__internalRegister.has(serviceName)) {
      throw new Error("Duplicate service");
    }
    this.__internalRegister.set(serviceName, { dependencies, constructorFn, service: NONE });

    // return "define"
    return this;
  };

  // modules are where the action takes place, they cannot have dependencies
  // between one another, and as such have no names.
  // These are not lazy but eager, all services must be defined beforehand.
  define.module = function (serviceDependencies, constructorFn) {

    const dependencies = this.__resolve(serviceDependencies);
    return return constructorFn.apply(null, dependencies);

  };

  // returns an array of initialized services, eagerly initializing any found in
  // while traversing the tree.
  define.__resolve = function (dependencies, results = []) {
    return dependencies.map(depName => {
      if (this.__internalRegister.has(depName)) {
        const { dependencies, constructorFn, service } = this.__internalRegister.get(depName);
        if (service === NONE) {
          // unitialized
          const subDeps = this.__resolve(dependencies);
          const initializedService = constructorFn.apply(null, subDeps);
          // save the new service
          this.__internalRegister.set(depName, { dependencies, constructorFn, service: initializedService });
          return initializedService;
        } else {
          return service;
        }
      }
      throw new Error("Service: " + name + " not found");
    })
  };


  // What you need to to now is just using the concat grunt plugin to push your
  // service code up, and your module code down.
```

Comment: Definitely a dependency management tool would be great. I've looked into Require.js a lot of times and can't figure out how to effectively slide it into our existing build process. I'm sure it can be done, but it ends up sucking up enough time that stakeholders go, "No. Move on. More important things to do." which is fair enough since our current build process already works. Each passing day I yearn more for implicit dependency management, though.

Comment: Having worked on a project in which some guy built up is own module management scheme (would not dare call it a dependency management) I assure you (and your stakeholder) it is most likelyu worth your while. I will elaborate a little how you could do it by "mimicking" require.js though for the exercise.

Comment: I try to provide a simple architecture to leverage the grunt concat plugin, don't be too hard on me.

Comment: Pretty neat, easy to understand, and I definitely appreciate your efforts here! I'm not sure I can give it a checkmark until I implement it (I mean, there are no SO gods watching me, but on principle!) but if I could give you 500 rep, I would. ;-) Will report back on the short-term method I end up with.

Comment: Thanks! Your problem I think was encountered by a lot of people during the development of the JS ecosystem so I will be interested in reading the solution you implement. As a matter of history, there are probably interesting issues in the jQuery repo for this, as they ended using requireJS iirc but started from a small core and expanded from it into neatly modularized core in a time in which build system where much less advanced than today.

Comment: So I ended up grabbing Barmar's "quick and easy" solution for now, so I threw it a checkmark. But dude, you went above and beyond, I have bookmarked this for when I circle back around, and I really do appreciate all the thought you gave it.